# How to rearrange one list based on a second list of indices

Tags: python, python-2.7, list

I have a list of 10 items, and another list of 10 randomly not repeated numbers as following:

```
l = [a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j]
m = [1,4,5,9,2,6,3,7,8,10]
```

I want to rearrange `l`, so that each item in `l` takes its corresponding index from `m`.

For example, `b` should become the fourth and `e` sould become the second.

I'm really stuck at the algorithm and the logic bugs me, so I don't have any idea on how to approach thi.

How can I do that?

Comment: Why do you want to sort the list `l`? You can always just use the indexes from `m` directly in any calculation: `l[m[i] - 1]`

Comment: @tobias_k I disagree with this duplicate. It's true that sorting `l` by `m` would produce the expected result, but "sorting" is not the same thing as "reordering". There are more efficient (i.e. `O(n)`) solutions to this problem than sorting, which is `O(n log n)`. I'd like to reopen this question.

Comment: It seems safe to assume `m` is the 10 distinct integers 1...10. No repetitions, no gaps, no non-integers.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you're just trying to get elements moved around based on the other lists positions, you can loop over all elements of `m` and grab that element of `l` using list comprehension

```
l2 = [l[i - 1] for i in m]
```

But if you do want the ordering based on the other list, you're going to need to zip them together, sort on the index, then extract the elements

```
[y for x,y in sorted(zip(m,l))]
```

Comment: I love you... Ordering based on another list (your second example) is something I was trying to figure out for a good while.

Answer (score 3):

**Note:** I'm assuming that `m` is always contiguous (i.e. there are no "gaps"), and starts at `1`.

If so, you can get what you want quite easily, using a list comprehension, `zip()` and `sorted()`.

Let's take it step by step:

```
>>> l = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j']
>>> m = [1, 4, 5, 9, 2, 6, 3, 7, 8, 10]
```

`zip()` pairs each element of `m` with an element of `l`:

```
>>> zip(m, l)
[(1, 'a'), (4, 'b'), (5, 'c'), (9, 'd'), (2, 'e'), (6, 'f'), (3, 'g'), (7, 'h'), (8, 'i'), (10, 'j')]
```

`sorted()` returns a sorted copy of the list of pairs:

```
>>> sorted(zip(m, l))
[(1, 'a'), (2, 'e'), (3, 'g'), (4, 'b'), (5, 'c'), (6, 'f'), (7, 'h'), (8, 'i'), (9, 'd'), (10, 'j')]
```

Finally, a list comprehension takes just the second item from each pair:

```
>>> [x for i, x in sorted(zip(m, l))]
['a', 'e', 'g', 'b', 'c', 'f', 'h', 'i', 'd', 'j']
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in linear O(n) time with the help of a dict:

```
l = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j']
m = [ 1,  4,  5,  9,  2,  6,  3,  7,  8,  10]

values_by_index = dict(zip(m, l))
result = [values_by_index[index+1] for index in range(len(m))]

print(result)
# output: ['a', 'e', 'g', 'b', 'c', 'f', 'h', 'i', 'd', 'j']
```

---

The first line creates dict that maps indices to values, which looks like this:

```
>>> values_by_index
{1: 'a', 4: 'b', 5: 'c', 9: 'd', 2: 'e', 6: 'f', 3: 'g', 7: 'h', 8: 'i', 10: 'j'}
```

In the second line we simply loop over the indices 1 through 10 and grab the corresponding value from the dict, which is a O(1) operation in the average case.

If you have 0-based indices, simply remove the `+1` from `index+1`.