# Change list's elements positions according to an array which tells where each element must be placed

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to change the the position of the elements of a python list
according to an array which tells where each element must be placed.

For example consider a list `["a","b","c"]`,
for these array values `[2,0,1]`=> the element at index position 0 (a) must go to index position 2,
element at index position 1 (b) go to index position 0
and element at index position 2  go to index position 1.

The expected list should look like this `["b","c","a"]`,

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I reorder a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2177590/how-can-i-reorder-a-list) Not the best duplicate target but the accepted answer is what you are looking for.

Comment: Array rotation, https://stackoverflow.com/a/17350541/4985099

Comment: How did you end up with `[2,0,1]`? Your problem would be a lot simpler if this array was indexed in the order of the new array instead of the old one. So `[1, 2, 0]` i.e. it is saying to get the first element pull our `arr[1]` etc. Then the solution is just `[arr[idx] for idx in [2, 0, 1]]`. If you explain the full problem, maybe someone can help you get this more sensible indexing in the first place?

Comment: @Georgy That is the inverse operation of what is asked for here.

Comment: @Georgy Question closed while the dup answers a different question?

Comment: `mylist = ["b", "c", "a"] ; myorder = [2, 0, 1] ; [mylist[i] for i in myorder]` (the answer referred to above) recovers the original list `['a', 'b', 'c']` -- i.e. the inverse operation

Comment: But if the input is `mylist = ["a", "b", "c"]`, then the output is `['c', 'a', 'b']` rather than the `['b', 'c', 'a']` that is wanted here.

Comment: @Sushanth This operation is not in general an array rotation. It happens to be with this particular input list of indices.

Comment: @alaniwi I agree this is not a dupe. But I also think it might be an [xy-problem](http://xyproblem.info/) which is why I've asked the OP where the index array comes from. I'll bet it will end up being a dupe. But we won't know until there is clarification so as it stands your solution is spot on.

Comment: @Dan Okay, that makes sense.

Comment: @alaniwi Ah! My mistake! Then the following dupe should fit here: [How to rearrange one list based on a second list of indices](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41549201/7851470)

Comment: @ThierryLathuille Could you please update the duplicate list?

Comment: @Georgy Yes I agree that that one is a valid dupe.

Comment: Not sure if there is a way to withdraw a reopen vote? (Happy to do, contingent on the list being updated as you indicated.)

Comment: @alaniwi Looks like [it's not possible yet](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/193061/378331)...

Comment: sorry for creating such a confusion , yes @georgy 's comment  was what i was looking for

Answer (score 2):

You could do:

```
lst = ["a", "b", "c"]
pos = [2, 0, 1]
d = dict(zip(pos, lst))  # {2: 'a', 0: 'b', 1: 'c'}
print([d[index] for index in range(len(lst))])  # ['b', 'c', 'a']
```